# onPress Handler is called infinite time after 2-3 press in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-hooks

```
import firebase from './Firebase';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-web';
import { setStatusBarNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { getFirestore, collection, query, getDocs, getDoc, Firestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
import deepFreezeAndThrowOnMutationInDev from 'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/deepFreezeAndThrowOnMutationInDev';


function Users() {

    const today = new Date();
    const yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    let mm = today.getMonth() + 1; // Months start at 0!
    let dd = today.getDate();
    if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd;
    if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm;
    var todayDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [filteredUsers, setFilteredUsers] = useState([]);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        
            firebase.firestore().collection('Testing').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                setUsers(
                    snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                        id: doc.id,
                        SMK: doc.data().SMK,
                        Name: doc.data().FullName,
                        todayStatus: getPresent(doc),
                    })));
                setFilteredUsers(
                    snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                        id: doc.id,
                        SMK: doc.data().SMK,
                        Name: doc.data().FullName,
                        todayStatus: getPresent(doc),
                    })));
                setIsLoaded(true);
            })
    },[]);

    const getPresent = (doc) => {
        let temp = doc.data().Attendance[todayDate];
        try {
            if (temp.status == "P") {
                return "P";
            }
            else {
                return "A";
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return "A";
        }
    }
    const searchFilter = (text) => {
        if (text) {
            const newData = users.filter(item => {
                const itemSMK = item.SMK;
                const itemName = item.Name;
                const textData = text;
                return (
                    item.SMK.indexOf(textData) > -1 ||
                    item.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(textData.toLowerCase()) > -1
                )
            });
            setFilteredUsers(newData);
            setSearch(text);
        }
        else {
            setFilteredUsers(users);
            setSearch(text);
        }
    }

    //button press handelers
    const markPresent = (id) => {
        let currentDoc = firebase.firestore().collection('Testing').doc(id);
        
        currentDoc.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            let snapData = snapshot.data();
            console.log('in present function');
            try {
                let tempObj = {
                    ...snapData.Attendance,
                    [todayDate]: {
                        Time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
                        Reason: '',
                        status: 'P'
                    },
                };
                snapData.Attendance = tempObj;
                currentDoc.update(snapData);
            } catch (error) {
                let tempObj = {
                    Attendance: {
                        [todayDate]: {
                            Time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
                            Reason: '',
                            status: 'P'
                        },
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
    const markAbsent = (id) => {
        let currentDocToDelete = firebase.firestore().collection('Testing').doc(id);
        currentDocToDelete.onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
            let snapDeleteData = snapshot.data();
            try {
                let tempDeleteObj = {
                    ...snapDeleteData.Attendance,
                    [todayDate]: {
                        status: 'A',
                    },
                };
                snapDeleteData.Attendance = tempDeleteObj;
                currentDocToDelete.update(snapDeleteData);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('Error in markAbsent function =>',error);
            }
        })
    }

    //returns view of particular list item of users
    const itemView = ({ item }) => {
        if (item.todayStatus == "P") {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>{item.SMK} : {item.Name} - present</Text>
                    <Button title='delete' onPress={() => markAbsent(item.id)} />
                </View>
            )
        }
        if(item.todayStatus=="A") {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>{item.SMK} : {item.Name} - absent</Text>
                    <Button title='present' onPress={() => markPresent(item.id)} />
                </View>
            )
        }
    }

    if (!isLoaded) {
        return <Text>Loading...</Text>
    }
    else {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <TextInput value={search} placeholder="search user here" onChangeText={searchFilter} />
                <FlatList data={filteredUsers} renderItem={itemView} />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
export default Users;
```

[Firestore document of one user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rw1z.png)

[Browser Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvQ5w.png)

When I click button 2-3 time.. it works perfectly but if i click it more than that then it goes into infinite loop.
handler is called automatically for both markPresent and markAbsent. and page keeps re-rendering.

Here I'm trying to fetch list of users and I have to mark them as present or absent.
whenever I try to click present after 2-3 users it goes into infinite loops

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need to do a `.get()` after the `.doc(id)`

try this

```
 const markPresent = async (id) => {
        let currentDoc =  await firebase.firestore().collection('Testing').doc(id).get();
```

[image]